# jquery, IE 8 Invalid argument error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, arguments

This code works fine in FF, Chrome & Safari, but IE 8 is throwing several Invalid Argument Errors when I run it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() {
        $('div .box').each(function() {
            $(this).width($(this).find('img').width());
        });
    });

</script>
```

[You can see it in context here](http://www.simonlast.co.uk/example/04.html): 
My html/css skills are more or less spotless but I'm practically clueless with jquery/javascript. I have searched but cant get a handle on what the error is and how to fix it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$(window).load` with `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: It helps if you use the full versions of script files whilst you are in development as they tend to give better error messages or at least break into code that can be debugged easily.

Comment: @ James, thanks for you input, I need to use the former because i need the images to load before it finds the widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code "$(this).find('img')" is not finding an image in all cases. Try:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('div .box').each(function() {
    var imageJQObject = $(this).find('img');
    if(imageJQObject.length > 0) {
      $(this).width(imageJQObject.width());
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Josh, I think you cracked it. Thanks man. 3 invalid arguments, 3 boxes without imgs. that makes sense. Your edited codes works perfectly. Is there anything i need to know about it?

Comment: Not really "if(imageJQObject.length > 0)" just checks to see if there are objects in imageJQObject before operating on it. The "imageJQObject.width()" code will return null if imageJQObject is empty and setting the width to null is no good.

Answer (score 0):

is there any other information on the exception, like which line it is? I'm getting the feeling that the width of the image is not being found so you are setting the width of `this` with null. try and substitute the img width with something like 100 and see if it still throws.

Comment: Hi Darki Z, thanks for the input.



line 116 char 165 of jquery js apparently.

To substitute the value, do I do like this? 


` $(window).load(function() {
   $('div .box').each(function() {
   $('100').width($(this).find('img').width());
   });
   });`

If that is correct, then you are also correct. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the markup on your page, you should have

```
$(window).load(function() {  
    $('div.box').each(function() {  
        $(this).width($(this).find('img').width());  
    });  
});
```

Notice the missing space between `div` and `.box`. If you write them separately, that means you are looking for all the elements with class `box` which are children of `div` while without the space it finds all the `div` with a class `box`

Comment: Thanks. Good point, though I think Josh below has cracked it.